# Tagging Git with Project Name

Tags: git, git-clone, git-tag

When tagging in Git, should I also add the project name? For instance, should I use

`git tag project-v1.0.0`

or just

`git tag v1.0.0`?

I ask because when someone clones my project, I want it to be cloned into a folder with the project name.

Comment: Tags are not folders. Tags do not modify the directory where your Git clones into.

Answer (score 1):

Keep tag simple, `1.0.0` is enough! The folder of clone doesn't depend from tags name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know this is not possible at git basis.
If project name is also name of top project directory (what is common aproach), then You could try cut command:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Which gives you full path of working directory.
Then just make a git hook, with sth similar:

```
$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)-v1.1.0
```